# How to get Time in twig?

Tags: twig, conditional-statements, ime

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/652x4.png)

Good Morning .. I want t add a condition like {% if time > 18 H and time < 22 H %} 
Payer

{%endif%}

I don't know how can i get the time in twig ??

Comment: why don't you just make a function in backend that does it and returns boolean. In twig you can then check with if statement if its true or not.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Please don't post code as an image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
{% if 'now'|date("H") > 18 and 'now'|date("H") < 22 %}
```

If you're talking about current time.